# KafkaEmbedded throwing NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$ValidString

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, embedded-kafka

I am trying to write functional test using embedded kafka. but getting below error while starting cluster:

> An exception or error caused a run to abort:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$ValidString.(Ljava/util/List;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/config/ConfigDef$1;)V
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$ValidString.(Ljava/util/List;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/config/ConfigDef$1;)V
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$ValidList.(ConfigDef.java:895)`

My Pom.xml has this dependancies

```
    `
        <dependency>
        <groupId>net.manub</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest-embedded-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <classifier>test</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the clients

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Its functional test for spark job. which is basically reading data from s3 and passing to kafka. So in functional test I am trying to start embedded kafka which is used for testing purpose. And test is failing  while starting that kafka.

Comment: `implicit val config: EmbeddedKafkaConfig = EmbeddedKafkaConfig(kafkaPort = 9092, zooKeeperPort = 2182)

    val topic: String = "test-topic"

    var appExecutorThread: ExecutorService = _


    before {
        SparkSession.clearActiveSession()
        EmbeddedKafka.stop()
        while (EmbeddedKafka.isRunning) Thread.sleep(100)
        EmbeddedKafka.start()(config)
        EmbeddedKafka.createCustomTopic(topic)(config)
        while (!EmbeddedKafka.isRunning) Thread.sleep(100)
        appExecutorThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    } ``

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [build.sbt](https://github.com/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka/blob/v0.10.0/build.sbt) or [pom.xml](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka_2.11/0.10.0/scalatest-embedded-kafka_2.11-0.10.0.pom) for scalatest-embedded-kafka 0.10.0. Both are using kafkaVersion = "0.10.1.0".

You can see in the files linked, that `kafka_2.11` dependency is not with scope [provided](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scopes.html), so you probably don't need to include the `kafka_2.11` dependency at all. If you do include it for some reason, you generally want to ensure that the class signatures needed in the transitive dependency are all present. The `README` file (same repo using the build.sbt link above) confirms that you probably don't need the kafka dependency. Your build tool should automatically bring in any transitive dependencies. I would try removing it, and or changing the version if that doesn't fix it.